# How do i get attribute value of the parent tag in a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have the following html structure:

```
<script>
    function process(){
        //how to retrive attr
        window.allert(attr); 
    }
</script>
<div attr="234234">
    <div onclick="process()">some content</div>
</div>
```

How do i get attribute value of the parent tag in a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass `this` to the function, then try [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) on the [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) of the current element:

```html
<script>
    function process(el){
        //how to retrive attr
        window.alert(el.parentNode.getAttribute('attr')); 
    }
</script>
<div attr="234234">
    <div onclick="process(this)">some content</div>
</div>
```

In jQuery, you can use [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) and [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$(el).parent().attr('attr')
```

You can also use `event.target` like the following way:

```html
<script>
    function process(e){
        //how to retrive attr
        window.alert(e.target.parentNode.getAttribute('attr')); 
    }
</script>
<div attr="234234">
    <div onclick="process(event)">some content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to determine where are you in the DOM without using 'this' as parameter?

Comment: @hal, you can also use `event.target`.....I have added another solution with that....plz check.

Answer (score 1):

while you're tagging jquery .. you can use `.parent()` and `.attr()`

```js
function process(el){
    alert($(el).parent().attr('attr'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div attr="234234">
    <div onclick="process(this)">some content</div>
</div>
```